# How to use the command \pdfextension in the luacode enviroment of the package luacode?

Tags: luatex

For example, when I try to compile this code in my document:

```
\begin{luacode}
\pdfextension literal direct{/Span <</ActualText (First paragraph on page one)>> BDC}
tex.print("my text")
\pdfextension literal direct{EMC}
\end{luacode}
```

I have a problem with the compilation of the document.

How I can use the command `\pdfextension` in Lua code?

Comment: please always make it easy for people to help you by providing a test file that reproduces the error.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't use luatex tex-commands like \pdfextension inside a luacode environment, it is only for luacode.

Comment: But what command i can use in luacode enviroment,to add span in the page.

Comment: You should make a complete example so that it is clear *where* in the page stream you want to inject the BDC operator.

Comment: Ok,in next comment you will se,how i try insert data in pdf,when start and end new paragraf.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
pdf.setcompresslevel(0)
b=0
function f(a)
texio.write_nl("Value "..a)
if a=="new_graf" then
if b%2==0 then
\pdfextension literal direct{/Span <</ActualText (test)>> BDC}
else
\pdfextension literal direct{EMC}
end
b=b+1
end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("buildpage_filter",f,"filter")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
paragraph one

paragraph two
\end{document}

Comment: Don't put code in the comments. Edit your question. And if you want me to see your comment you should ping me with @UlrikeFischer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91326/discussion-between-aleksandr-kozlovskiy-and-ulrike-fischer).

Answer (score 5):

I translated your example in the comments to something that compiles below.

### But ...

You are using the wrong callback. If you look in the pdf you will see something like this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%ÌÕÁÔÅØÐÄÆ
/Span <</ActualText (test)>> BDC EMC 3 0 obj
<< /Length 205 >>
```

This means that your BDC-operator ended **outside** the page stream. The pdf is broken.

The documentation describes the callback like this:

> This callback is called whenever LuaTEX is ready to move stuff to the main vertical list. You can
>   use this callback to do specialized manipulation of the page building stage like imposition or
>   column balancing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
pdf.setcompresslevel(0)
b=0
function f(a)
 texio.write_nl("Value "..a)
 if a=="new_graf" then
  if b%2==0
  then
   pdf.print ("direct","/Span <</ActualText (test)>> BDC ")
  else
   pdf.print ("direct","EMC ")
  end
  b=b+1
 end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("buildpage_filter",f,"filter")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
 paragraph one

 paragraph two
\end{document}
```